# Missing ECTS requirements, still trying to apply, should I mention it on my motivation letter?

Tags: application-cover-letter

A summary of my situation :

- I am currently applying to ETH Zurich in their Data Science and Computer Science programs
- I did my first year of undergrad as a Music Major, and my 2nd and 3rd year as a Computer Science Major
- My 3rd year average grade is 18.7 / 20 ( 93% ) ranked 1st
- My 2nd year average grade is 18.04 / 20 ( 90% ) ranked 1st
- The 3rd year school has a better reputation than the 2nd year school.

Because of my music major, I'm missing about half of the ECTS needed in the Computer Science program. I am missing more ECTS than "allowed". I would like to know if I should mention it in my cover letter? I could say something along the lines of " I know I am missing some requirements, but I am willing to catch up on the subjects where I lack knowledge provided I can attend the lectures provided at ETHZ. As you can see I transitioned from a Music Major to a Computer Science without problem despite lacking fundamentals knowledge "

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Call them beforehand by phone and ask if you are formally allowed to apply if you are missing the credits and explain your situation. There is not much point for a full application if already the admin people would put it on the "no" stack without a real decision maker even seening it. 
If you get a "go ahead" via phone then state this fact in your letter.

Comment: understood i will do that